# Do not colour "word" colours in rainbow-mode

Tags: colors

In `rainbow-mode`, is it possible to toggle colouring only "words" or only "hexadicimals"? I don't see a variable I could set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is in the library `rainbow-mode.el`, particularly the functions `rainbow-turn-on` and `rainbow-turn-off`. You can make copies of these functions that include or omit the appropriate sets of commands to get the result you want.

A quick and dirty example:

```
(defun rainbow-turn-off-hexadecimal ()
  "Turn off hexadecimal colours in rainbow-mode."
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-remove-keywords
   nil
   `(,@rainbow-hexadecimal-colors-font-lock-keywords)))

(defun rainbow-turn-off-words ()
  "Turn off word colours in rainbow-mode."
  (interactive)
  (font-lock-remove-keywords
   nil
   `(,@rainbow-x-colors-font-lock-keywords
     ,@rainbow-latex-rgb-colors-font-lock-keywords
     ,@rainbow-r-colors-font-lock-keywords
     ,@rainbow-html-colors-font-lock-keywords
     ,@rainbow-html-rgb-colors-font-lock-keywords)))
```

With these functions defined, call `rainbow-mode`, and then `M-x rainbow-turn-off-words` to remove the highlighting from words, and leave it for the hexadecimals. Note that the colours won't change immediately, it will happen next time the buffer is 're-fontified'. You can force this by calling `font-lock-fontify-buffer`.

You can reset your colors by turning rainbow mode off and on again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and the tip!